# PostgreSQL returns Extra Sorting In Group By + In Statement Query

Tags: postgresql, indexing, group-by, query-performance

I have a query like below:

```sql
SELECT 
    MAX(m.org_id) as orgId,
    MAX(m.org_name) as orgName,
    MAX(m.app_id) as appId,
    MAX(r.country_or_region) as country, 
    MAX(r.local_spend_currency) as currency, 
    SUM(r.local_spend_amount) as spend,
    SUM(r.impressions) as impressions
    ...
FROM report r  
LEFT JOIN metadata m 
    ON m.org_id = r.org_id
    AND m.campaign_id = r.campaign_id
    AND m.ad_group_id = r.ad_group_id 
WHERE (r.report_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-10-10') 
    AND r.org_id IN (1138740,1212430,1236970,1238450,1238520,1200980, .... more than 50)
GROUP BY r.country_or_region, r.ad_group_id, r.keyword_id, r.keyword, r.text  
OFFSET 0
LIMIT 20
```

And Explain results look like below:

```
Limit  (cost=24.47..24.57 rows=1 width=681)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=24.47..24.57 rows=1 width=681)
        Group Key: r.country_or_region, r.ad_group_id, r.keyword_id, r.keyword, r.text
        ->  Sort  (cost=24.47..24.48 rows=1 width=181)
              Sort Key: r.country_or_region, r.ad_group_id, r.keyword_id, r.keyword, r.text
              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=12.28..24.46 rows=1 width=181)
                    ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on report r  (cost=12.00..16.15 rows=1 width=82)
                          Recheck Cond: ((report_date >= '2019-01-01'::date) AND (report_date <= '2019-10-10'::date) AND (org_id = ANY ('{1138740,1212430,1236970,1238450,1238520,1200980 ...}'::numeric[])))
                          ->  Bitmap Index Scan on idx_date_org_cty  (cost=0.00..12.00 rows=1 width=0)
                                Index Cond: ((report_date >= '2019-01-01'::date) AND (report_date <= '2019-10-10'::date) AND (org_id = ANY ('{1138740,1212430,1236970,1238450,1238520,1200980,1221910 ...}'::numeric[])))
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_16569_primary on ad_group_metadata m  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=114)
                          Index Cond: ((org_id = r.org_id) AND (campaign_id = r.campaign_id) AND (ad_group_id = r.ad_group_id))
```

Implemented: "VACUUM FULL ANALYZE".

Explain Analyze:

```
Limit  (cost=854136.16..854138.08 rows=20 width=563) (actual time=1755.154..1755.369 rows=20 loops=1)
  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=854136.16..874013.30 rows=206845 width=563) (actual time=1755.153..1755.363 rows=20 loops=1)
        Group Key: r.country_or_region, r.ad_group_id, r.keyword_id, r.keyword, r.text
        ->  Sort  (cost=854136.16..854661.68 rows=210206 width=222) (actual time=1755.069..1755.122 rows=196 loops=1)
              Sort Key: r.country_or_region, r.ad_group_id, r.keyword_id, r.keyword, r.text
              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 52960kB
              ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=3196.06..813278.43 rows=210206 width=222) (actual time=113.734..1384.338 rows=152571 loops=1)
                    Hash Cond: ((r.org_id = m.org_id) AND (r.campaign_id = m.campaign_id) AND (r.ad_group_id = m.ad_group_id))
                    ->  Index Scan using idx_orgid_date_campid on report r  (cost=0.56..800305.56 rows=210206 width=119) (actual time=19.898..1192.910 rows=152571 loops=1)
                          Index Cond: ((org_id = ANY ('{1138740,1212430,1236970,1238450,1238520 ...}'::bigint[])) AND (report_date >= '2019-09-01'::date) AND (report_date <= '2019-10-10'::date))
                    ->  Hash  (cost=1739.09..1739.09 rows=41509 width=119) (actual time=93.659..93.659 rows=41509 loops=1)
                          Buckets: 32768  Batches: 2  Memory Usage: 3550kB
                          ->  Seq Scan on ad_group_metadata m  (cost=0.00..1739.09 rows=41509 width=119) (actual time=0.006..76.137 rows=41509 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.815 ms
Execution Time: 1762.834 ms
```

1. There is no sorting in my query but explain analyze shows extra sorting. I couldn't understand why?
2. This query works very well for a single IN value. But for more IN values, it is not effective. How can I improve it?

Comment: I guess sorting is the easiest way (or at least PostgreSQL thinks this) to get the rows into groups. So first sorting and afterwards just iterating over the results and starting a new group every time one of the columns changes. So it is not necessary (respectively far easier and more performant) to check if there is already a group that fits a record or if you have to come up with a new one. Regarding your performance question, I feel like indexes ```report (report_date org_id)``` and ```ad_group_metadata (org_id, campaign_id, ad_group_id)``` might help. But you might already have one or both

Comment: @Islingre, yes I have both of them (Explain shows them). This query is not very complex query and it is working in Mysql so effectively. I wonder there is a special case or special index type about IN statement?

Comment: From the ```EXPLAIN``` I have not been sure about the column order. This might have some big inpact (at least for the first index). Perhaps run an ```EXPLAIN ANALYZE``` to see, if the estimates correspond to your data. Perhaps you will also see then what the origin of the problem is. After all, expected cost of 24.57 should really lead to an instant result. Perhaps the statistics for your tables are wrong? A ```VACUUM FULL``` on the tables might help as well.

Comment: @Islingre The query works really slow. Vacuum full effects performance also?

Comment: The vacuum might change the statistics and this might change the query plan which might again change the performance. Please run the ```VACUUM FULL``` to both tables and afterwards add the output of ```EXPLAIN ANALYZE``` to the question. What means "really slow"? (Perhaps using ```\timing``` tells you more if you use ```psql```. But ```EXPLAIN ANALYZE``` will have timing data anyways, as far as I am concerned.)

Comment: @Islingre, ok I'll run it then I will share details.

Comment: @Islingre, I did "VACUUM FULL". And I added the "explain analyze" results to question. FYI

Comment: Apparently you have configured a very small amount of `work_mem` for your Postgres installation. That means Postgres can't use a hash aggregate. But the work_mem is also so small that it has to do that sorting on disk. Your index scan looks quite slow as well. It takes 1.3 seconds to read roughly 25MB. What kind of harddisk are you using?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, aws(m5.large, 150GB Disk(100GB Free), 8GB RAM)

Comment: I don't know what `m5.large` means. Is that a SSD? Spinning Harddisk? Directly (physically) attached to the server? Attached as a SAN or some other networking solution? It does look like quite a slow disk.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Concepts.DBInstanceClass.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, my work_mem looks 4mb. Is it normal or should I increase it?

Answer (score 0):

In order to fulfill the GROUP BY, it has basically two options.  Use a HashAgg, or get the rows in order by the GROUP BY columns (either by sorting, or by using an index which delivers the in order).  It has chosen the latter.

Either it thinks the sort will be faster than the HashAgg, or it thinks the HashAgg will use too much memory.  (HashAgg cannot spill to disk the way Sort or HashJoin can).  Or it thinks the two will be tied and arbitrarily went with one (given your expected row counts, that seems likely).  One thing you can do to help decide is to `set enable_sort=off` and see what happens.  Using `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` rather than just `EXPLAIN` could as well.  Increasing "work_mem" could also help, but without seeing `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` it is hard to say how much to increase it.

> and it is working in Mysql so effectively

This isn't very helpful, unless you can show us the mysql equivalent of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)` for comparison.

Comment: "Explain Analyze" results were added.